# How to replace a view

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

Application requires more than one window (Lets call A,B,C). Each window has more than one view (table views, image views as well as web view). Lets say window A has three views (x, y,z) and window B has three views (d,e,f). Application needs to display images of different size on orientation change.

I have achieved the same using gesture event listener and looping through windows for views and replacing the view with new images. The problem I have is when we navigate from one window to other and the orientation changes, the loading of view after looping goes for a toss. Is there a better way to achieve the same ?

Is there a method in titanium like following code to replace a view ?

```
var self=Ti.UI.currentWindow
var newView=Ti.UI.createImageView({image:'abc.png'})
self.replace(self.children[1],newView )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately there is now `replace` method.**

You need to remove the whole view and add it again but this can cause a wrong layout if you have more than one view on a same level. The implementation then depends on the layout which was set (`vertical`, `horizontal`, `composite` etc).

For example in `vertical` layout removing an item and simply add a new one would remove your specified item but appends the new one at the end since you can't specify in which order it should be added.

If you have a `composite` layout you can specify absolute positions but adding a new view causes a higher `zIndex` for this view so that it will hide views that were previously added at the same/similar position.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply change the image link ?

```
var self = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
self.children[1].image = 'bcd.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

[Well you could always lock the orientation of your window](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-orientationModes). But this isnt exactly good practice (especially for iOS).

Generally orientation changes are handled pretty well if you define the `width` and `height` of your views to be percentages or `Ti.UI.FILL`, if you have a `composite` layout. Check that you are not giving the views absolute coordinates as this could [cause layout problems.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-layout) If you have a vertical or horizontal layout you usually don't have to worry about orientation change, unless you did not nest your views in a main container correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Prasad,

If this is about just ensuring that the images look good on different orientations,you can make use of the different folders provided by Titanium in the android/images folder.You can just make different images for each of the orientations and device sizes.For IOS you can change just the images on orientation change as you are already doing.

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Using+density-specific+resources+on+Android

If you are concernced about the layout there are couple of things you can do:

1.Give all the height or width values in percentages.This way all elements will be re sized once the orientation changes automatically.

2.On each window open check if the orientation is vertical or horizontal by default and accordingly set the image attribute of the imageView.

```
Ti.UI.orientation
```

This property will give you the orientation of the window by default.Values of this property could be this

Ti.UI.PORTRAIT

Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT

Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT

Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT

Use "if else"  and accordingly set the images.